# How to paste corresponding lines in multi-cursor mode in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy-paste

I have a block of text with multiple lines copied to the clipboard.
I have multiple cursors in my editor, added with Ctrl+Click (on Linux).
I want to be able to paste each line from the clipboard into a corresponding cursor.
Example:

Clipboard:

```
1
2
3
```

Cursors:

```
A|
AB|
ABC|
```

Desired result:

```
A1
AB2
ABC3
```

How would I got about this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late but here's how you can do multiline copy pasting:

1. Move cursor to bottom right (after `3`)
2. While holding down `⌥ Option + ⇧ Shift` keys, drag cursor to top left before `1`
3. Copy lines using `⌘ Command + C`
4. Move cursor to bottom after `ABC`
5. While holding down `⌥ Option + ⇧ Shift` keys, drag cursor to top left before `A` like before
6. Go to end of each line with `⌘ Command + → Left arrow`
7. Paste lines using `⌘ Command + V`
   [image: For VScode version 1.36.1]

You can also use `⌥ Option + ⇧ Shift + I` while your block of text is selected to get a cursor for each line